# MYSQL query that only give the first occurrence of each group that can be saved as a View

Tags: mysql

I'm struggling to correctly query what appears to be simple but the only solution I was able to come up with I can't save as a view since it contained a variable. What I am trying to do is select only the first occurrence of each StartDate/idcustomerL combination.  When I try to use Group by StartDate, idcustomerL it doesn't give me the first result (I tried ordering it different ways with no luck either).
Below is the table I am working with.

StartDate = Each StartDateC and StartDateR for each customer
total = day differential of StartDateC + StartDateR from StartDate (I did this to create the order needed to determine what StartDate to use)

Table

```
+------------+------------+------------+------------+-------+
| StartDate  | idcustomer | StartDateC | StartDateR | total |
+------------+------------+------------+------------+-------+
| 2018-11-06 | 20         | 2018-11-06 | 2018-10-01 | 36    |
+------------+------------+------------+------------+-------+
| 2018-11-06 | 20         | 2018-11-06 | 2018-01-01 | 309   |
+------------+------------+------------+------------+-------+
| 2018-10-01 | 20         | 2018-10-01 | 2018-10-01 | 0     |
+------------+------------+------------+------------+-------+
| 2018-10-01 | 20         | 2018-08-30 | 2018-10-01 | 32    |
+------------+------------+------------+------------+-------+
| 2018-10-01 | 20         | 2018-10-01 | 2018-01-01 | 273   |
+------------+------------+------------+------------+-------+
| 2018-08-30 | 20         | 2018-08-30 | 2018-01-01 | 241   |
+------------+------------+------------+------------+-------+
| 2018-10-01 | 62         | 2018-10-01 | 2018-10-01 | 0     |
+------------+------------+------------+------------+-------+
| 2018-10-01 | 62         | 2018-08-30 | 2018-10-01 | 32    |
+------------+------------+------------+------------+-------+
| 2018-10-01 | 62         | 2018-10-01 | 2018-01-01 | 273   |
+------------+------------+------------+------------+-------+
| 2018-08-30 | 62         | 2018-08-30 | 2018-01-01 | 241   |
+------------+------------+------------+------------+-------+
```

This is the result I need to get and I need to be able to save the query as a view.

```
+------------+------------+------------+------------+-------+
| StartDate  | idcustomer | StartDateC | StartDateR | total |
+------------+------------+------------+------------+-------+
| 2018-11-06 | 20         | 2018-11-06 | 2018-10-01 | 36    |
+------------+------------+------------+------------+-------+
| 2018-10-01 | 20         | 2018-10-01 | 2018-10-01 | 0     |
+------------+------------+------------+------------+-------+
| 2018-08-30 | 20         | 2018-08-30 | 2018-01-01 | 241   |
+------------+------------+------------+------------+-------+
| 2018-10-01 | 62         | 2018-10-01 | 2018-10-01 | 0     |
+------------+------------+------------+------------+-------+
| 2018-08-30 | 62         | 2018-08-30 | 2018-01-01 | 241   |
+------------+------------+------------+------------+-------+
```

I can get the result I am looking for with the following but I can not save it as a view because of the @count so I need to find another solution.

```
Select (@count := @count + 1) AS rowNumber, StartDate, idcustomerL, StartDateC, StartDateR, Test as totals 
from test 
CROSS JOIN (SELECT @count := 0) AS dummy 
Group by StartDate,idcustomerL order by idcustomerL, StartDate desc, totals
```

Comment: Please edit the question and change table to proper formatting. You can use https://www.tablesgenerator.com/text_tables  Although it would be best, if you can setup a https://www.db-fiddle.com on what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that the "first" row within a group of `idcustomer` and `StartDate` is defined as the one having the lowest `total` value.

We can determine the lowest `total` value for the specified group in a [Derived Table](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/derived-tables.html). We will then `JOIN` this result-set back to the main table using the lowest total value, `idcustomer` and `StartDate`. This will give us the complete row against the lowest total value in a group.

---

[**Demo on DB Fiddle**](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/tmWQ5ozF8mkTTG2Zhd9YV6/0)

**Query**

```
SELECT
  t.*
FROM 
  test AS t
JOIN 
(
  SELECT 
    StartDate, 
    idcustomer, 
    MIN(total) AS lowest_total 
  FROM test 
  GROUP BY 
    StartDate, 
    idcustomer
) AS dt 
  ON dt.StartDate = t.StartDate AND 
     dt.idcustomer = t.idcustomer AND 
     dt.lowest_total = t.total;
```

**Result**

```
| StartDate  | idcustomer | StartDateC | StartDateR | total |
| ---------- | ---------- | ---------- | ---------- | ----- |
| 2018-11-06 | 20         | 2018-11-06 | 2018-10-01 | 36    |
| 2018-10-01 | 20         | 2018-10-01 | 2018-10-01 | 0     |
| 2018-08-30 | 20         | 2018-08-30 | 2018-01-01 | 241   |
| 2018-10-01 | 62         | 2018-10-01 | 2018-10-01 | 0     |
| 2018-08-30 | 62         | 2018-08-30 | 2018-01-01 | 241   |
```

---

Now, you can create the view using this query (without the user defined variables).

```
CREATE VIEW test_view AS 
SELECT
  t.*
FROM 
  test AS t
JOIN 
(
  SELECT 
    StartDate, 
    idcustomer, 
    MIN(total) AS lowest_total 
  FROM test 
  GROUP BY 
    StartDate, 
    idcustomer
) AS dt 
  ON dt.StartDate = t.StartDate AND 
     dt.idcustomer = t.idcustomer AND 
     dt.lowest_total = t.total
```

Comment: Madhur, Thank you very much!!